# Why my Laravel routes work in Laravel 7 but does not work in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, controller, email-verification

This is my route which is working nice in laravel 7 :

```
Route::get('/verify','Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser')->name('verify.user');
```

But in Laravel 8 it does not  work. It display an error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionEx. Target class [Auth\RegisterController] does not exist.
```

Comment: It would be `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`

Comment: Laravel has changed route method in version 8. `Route::get('/verify', [RegisterController::class, 'verifyUser'])->name('verify.user');` Don't forget to add `use Auth\RegisterController` statement. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

Comment: Thanks, it works for me also adding use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8, the controller namespace for the application in your `RouteServiceProvider` is commented by default:

```
// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

According to documentation:

> In previous releases of Laravel, the RouteServiceProvider contained a $namespace property. This property's value would automatically be prefixed onto controller route definitions and calls to the action helper / URL::action method. In Laravel 8.x, this property is null by default. This means that no automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel." [Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing Namespace Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates)

You can import the namespace like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

// then
Route::get('/verify','RegisterController@verifyUser')->name('verify.user');
```

Or you can use fully qualified name as below:

```
Route::get('/verify', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'verifyUser'])->name('verify.user');

// or 
Route::get('/verify', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser')->name('verify.user');;
```

Answer (score -1):

following is the new way to define routes in laravel 8

```
Route::get('/verify', [Auth\RegisterController::class, 'verifyUser'])->name('verify.user');
```